# How to turn one XML record with sub nodes into multiple records without XSLT or SQL

Tags: c#, xml

I need to figure out how to turn one XML record with sub nodes into multiple records using C#. Yes, I know it would be easier to do this using XSLT but that isn't an option.  I have an XML file that must be modified to be used by 5 different uses so I need a common starting point.

Forgive my lack of understanding but nothing I can find seems to go in this direction.  Everything goes in the other direction.  Here is a sample of my code and file.

The source file.

```
<inventoryitems>
  <inventoryitem>
    <id>11101</id>
    <displayname>LG HAMBURGER PATTY</displayname>
    <basemeasure>EACH</basemeasure>
    <reportingmeasure>EACH</reportingmeasure>
    <measures>
      <measure>
        <name>CS</name>
        <factor>1.000000</factor>
        <isactive>1</isactive>
      </measure>
      <measure>
        <name>ST</name>
        <factor>8.000000</factor>
        <isactive>1</isactive>
      </measure>
      <measure>
        <name>EACH</name>
        <factor>120.000000</factor>
        <isactive>1</isactive>
      </measure>
    </measures>
    <categories>
      <category>
        <name>MEATS</name>
      </category>
    </categories>
    <locations />
    <skus />
  </inventoryitem>
  <inventoryitem>
    <id>11102</id>
    <displayname>SM HAMBURGER PATTY</displayname>
    <basemeasure>EACH</basemeasure>
    <reportingmeasure>EACH</reportingmeasure>
    <measures>
      <measure>
        <name>ST</name>
        <factor>6.000000</factor>
        <isactive>1</isactive>
      </measure>
      <measure>
        <name>CS</name>
        <factor>1.000000</factor>
        <isactive>1</isactive>
      </measure>
      <measure>
        <name>EACH</name>
        <factor>96.000000</factor>
        <isactive>1</isactive>
      </measure>
    </measures>
    <categories>
      <category>
        <name>MEATS</name>
      </category>
    </categories>
    <locations />
    <skus />
  </inventoryitem>
  <inventoryitem>
    <id>11202</id>
    <displayname>BREAD  SM BUN 4</displayname>
    <basemeasure>EACH</basemeasure>
    <reportingmeasure>EACH</reportingmeasure>
    <measures>
      <measure>
        <name>TR</name>
        <factor>1.000000</factor>
        <isactive>1</isactive>
      </measure>
      <measure>
        <name>EACH</name>
        <factor>30.000000</factor>
        <isactive>1</isactive>
      </measure>
    </measures>
    <categories>
      <category>
        <name>BAKERY</name>
      </category>
    </categories>
    <locations />
    <skus />
  </inventoryitem>
</inventoryitems>
```

What I need to get would look something like this.

```
<data>
  <row InventoryItemId="11201" ItemDescription="BREAD LG BUN 5" CategoryName="BAKERY" Measure="TR" />
  <row InventoryItemId="11201" ItemDescription="BREAD LG BUN 5" CategoryName="BAKERY" Measure="EACH" />
</data>
```

I was able to write the code to mode the value to an attribute when the is only one node but I am at a loss on what to do when there is a sub node with multiple values.

```
invlist = results.Substring(results.IndexOf("<inventoryitems>"), (results.IndexOf("</inventoryitemsresponsedata>") - results.IndexOf("<inventoryitems>")));

                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                XmlNode nd = doc.CreateNode("element", "data", "");
                doc.AppendChild(nd);

                //XmlNode rw = doc.CreateNode("element", "row", "");
                //nd.AppendChild(rw);

                var invitems = new XmlDocument { InnerXml = invlist };

                XmlNode result = doc.ImportNode(invitems.DocumentElement, true);
                nd.AppendChild(result);

                XmlNodeList ndList = doc.SelectNodes("data/inventoryitems/inventoryitem");
                foreach (XmlNode id in ndList)
                {
                    XmlNode idnode = id.SelectSingleNode("id");
                    if (idnode != null)
                    {
                        XmlNode rw = doc.CreateNode("element", "row", "");
                        nd.AppendChild(rw);

                        var attribute = doc.CreateAttribute("InventoryItemId");
                        attribute.Value = idnode.InnerXml;

                        var Description = doc.CreateAttribute("ItemDescription");
                        Description.Value = id.SelectSingleNode("displayname").InnerXml;

                        rw.Attributes.Append(attribute);
                        rw.Attributes.Append(Description);

                    }

                    XmlNodeList msList = id.SelectNodes("measures/measure");
                    foreach (XmlNode mes in msList)
                    {
                        XmlNode msnode = mes.SelectSingleNode("name");
                        if (msnode != null)
                        {
                            var attribute = doc.CreateAttribute("Measure");
                            attribute.Value = msnode.InnerXml;
                            //rw.Attributes.Append(attribute);
                            mes.Attributes.Append(attribute);
                        } 
                    }
              }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Update: This is what I am getting.

```
<data>
  <row InventoryItemId="11201" ItemDescription="BREAD LG BUN 5" CategoryName="BAKERY" />
  <inventoryitem>
    <measures>
      <measure Measure="TR"></measure>
      <measure Measure="EACH"></measure>
    </measures>
    <locations />
    <skus />
  </inventoryitem>
</data>
```

Comment: What's the problem with your approach? It seems reasonable

Comment: I can't figure out how to get two records if I have two different measure values.  See my second example, that is what I am trying for but can't figure out how to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  By wrapping each node inside a row node loop I get the results I was looking for.

```
                   var item = idnode.InnerXml;

                    XmlNodeList rwList = doc.SelectNodes(String.Format("data/row[@InventoryItemId='{0}']",item));
                    var rwCount = rwList.Count;
                    foreach (XmlNode rw in rwList)
                    {
                        XmlNodeList msList = id.SelectNodes("measures/measure");                        
                        foreach (XmlNode mes in msList)
                        {                            
                            XmlNode msnode = mes.SelectSingleNode("name");
                            {                                
                                var attribute = doc.CreateAttribute("Measure");
                                attribute.Value = msnode.InnerXml;

                                if (rwCount > 0)
                                {
                                    rw.Attributes.Append(attribute);
                                    rwCount--;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    XmlNode clonenode = rw.Clone();
                                    clonenode.Attributes.Append(attribute);
                                    nd.AppendChild(clonenode);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```